# Extract URL from content

Tags: wordpress

I have created a function where I need to extract URL from content. I don't know where did I go wrong. Here's my code..

```
 function strip_url_content($content){
    $strip = explode("\n", esc_html($content));
    foreach($strip as $key => $single){
        if (!filter_var($single, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === true) {
            unset($strip[$key]);
        }
    }
    return implode( ' ', $strip );
}
```

Comment: show me your print_r($content)  data

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    [1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENVW3uZ3a-4 
    [2] => 
    [3] => It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] =>   
)

Comment: just echo $content[1]

Comment: No I need to extract the URL in which ever array it may be